Kids tv show with a boy and two alien-looking friends
I have been trying to find out the name of this show that I will explain below, It's really irritating because I have tried everywhere and I cannot find it. I can't say what year the show aired or where in the world, but I'm from the UK and I was probably watching it around the years of 2005 or something like that, I apologise that, isn't helpful but I am horrible at years and my memory is awful. 
The show was about a boy, I believe with brown hair, hard to say and I can't remember his name. He had two alien looking friends which he went on adventures with. One was a skinny green alien looking thing, that was the more nervous and sensible one out of the friends. The other was a pink hippo looking thing that loved dangerous adventures and usually always said 'oh joy/oh boy!' Thinking about it now, they could be imaginery friends. 
Most of his adventures are sort of made up in his mind I believe. A few of his adventures, he has a alarm clock that he screws backwards to go back to the jurassic period or use it to somehow clean up his room. There are a lot of episodes where they shrink in size. One episode they shrink and the green friend is kidnapped by an old, blind spider that wants to eat him. Another time, the green guy is stuck in ice cream that was dropped by the boy before they shrunk. 
They even went in a subramine and went through the water pipes. There was one episode where I think it was a goat, stole all the sheep and a baby lamp the boy was looking after.
To me it was either stop motion or claymation, or probably both. But again I really tried and I'm really hoping someone could help me find it. 

This is Oscar and Friends, a New Zealand claymation series from the mid-90s.

The show is about a 7-year-old boy named Oscar, who, with his [two] imaginary friends, goes from adventure to adventure. In this fantasy life of his, Bugsy, a bright green, bug-eyed mischievous coward, and Doris, a daring, eccentric [pink] girl and Oscar's confidante, are there to rescue him in danger and lend a hand.

All the things you mentioned happened there. Here's the one where Bugsy fell into the ice-cream:




I cannot express how thankful I am, thank you so much!!! I really appreciate the help. Hope you have a wonderful day~

At first my guess would be Fantastic Max but upon further details provided, I'm not sure if this matches up. Max is playing with toys that come to life. One is a little green alien, etc...
http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/Fantastic_Max_3355.jpg
I'm not sure about the stop motion or the pink character though. 

Nope, its not Fantastic Max, but thank you for trying to help. I am also still unsure, about the type of animation, It looked a bit like claymation but also had another side to it.
